# Laravel multi-tenancy application with addon domain

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, multi-tenant

Here is the concept we're trying to achieve:

- our main domain is pen.com, is a front-page of our service, containing pricing information, blog, contact page, etc;
- pen.com/signup - is the entry point where users can sign up and open a shop under custom subdomain.
- admin.pen.com - is the application control panel where we can see the key metrics of our app, manage the subscriptions, etc. No one except of us should have an access to this area;
- {shop}.pen.com,{shop}.pen.com/contact-us,{shop}.pen.com/signup,{shop}.pen.com/signin,{shop}.pen.com/... - a user's storefront and associate routes as regular web application
- {shop}.pen.com/dashboard - Users roll have to be determined on the fly and serve the correct dashboard
  i.e a shop admin/owner will manage shop.

User - is an entity, representing a real person (e.g. who may login or register);

Shop - an entity representing an online store for certain company. Shop domain is unique accross our platform.

**Now we have manage to achieve this but the challenge here is adding CNAME to this individual subdomain or addon domain in laravel or through Cpanel of our host.**
please advice.

Comment: What's the question? This guy explained it pretty good - https://medium.com/@ashokgelal/a-full-featured-multi-tenant-app-with-laravel-part-1-4049a3cc229d

Comment: how do we add CNAME to individual subdomain or addon domain in laravel or through Cpanel of our host?

Comment: I've gone through that material @senty. the question is how to hook up custom domain name to the subdomain created in the laravel application?

Comment: You need to configure nginx to accept subdomains and then use Laravel's [Sub-domain Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing)

Comment: i've done that but how do i set addon domain to point to the subdomain?

Comment: The terminology is "wildcard subdomain" - check it with your dns company

Comment: alright. thank you